# $\mathbb{Z}:= \mathbb{N} \cup (-\mathbb{N}) \cup \{0\}$, $a,b \in \mathbb{Z}$, when $a \le b$?

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Let $\mathbb{Z}:= \mathbb{N} \cup (-\mathbb{N}) \cup \{0\}$,  and $a,b \in \mathbb{Z}$, when $a \le b$?
Thanks in advance!!

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: @anonymous, let $ a,b \in \mathbb{Z} $, when $ a \le b $??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$a\le b$$ if and only if $$b-a\in \mathbb{N}\cup \{0\}$$

Comment: but $b-a$  is defined operation in $\mathbb{N}$ or in $\mathbb{Z}$?

Comment: $b-a$ is defined in $\mathbb{Z}$.

Comment: okok... but, how is it defined?

Comment: @GarnakOlegovitc, if you want your question answered in terms of some specific starting place, please share what that is.  There are two ways to consider $\le$ on the integers, either directly or by considering $\mathbb{N}$ as the "positive" integers.  Either can be proved from the other, as I did for you.